# How to do styling for HEADERS in HTML table

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk

My file contain below comma separated data , where first row is the header

**File data :**

```
Name,Rollno,Course,Language,Subject,Awarded
Vilas,1,MBA,Account,MB,1
Ajay,2,MMM,Subject Matter,SU,2
Fedrick,33,MMS,Mct,SC,3
```

**Partial working code :**

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>" >> n.html
echo "<html>" >> n.html
echo "<head>" >> n.html
echo "<style>" >> n.html
echo "table, th, td {" >> n.html
echo "border: 1px solid black;" >> n.html
echo "border-collapse: collapse;" >> n.html
echo "}" >> n.html
echo "</style>" >> n.html
echo "</head>" >> n.html
echo "<body>" >> n.html

awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "<table>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}'  A.txt >> n.html

echo "</body>" >> n.html
echo "</html>" >> n.html
```

**Output of code :**

[image: Output of above code]

**Needed Headers like below Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: @Archemar i am not good at awk , can you do it and explain in details

Comment: That's not a shell or awk question, youalready have the awk code to output HTML for a table you're asking for the HTML to color the background in the table cells - a simple google search or creating such a table with an html editor will tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
cat <<EOF > n.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {background-color: yellow} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
EOF

awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "<table>";} 
    NR==1 { cell="th" ; }
   { print "<tr>";
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "<%s>%s</%s>",cell,$i,cell ; 
     print "</tr>" ; cell="td" } 
   END{print "</table>"}' a.txt >> n.html

echo "</body>" >> n.html
echo "</html>" >> n.html
```

where

- I collapsed multiple `echo` in a here document.
- I deploy a multi line `awk` program for readability.
- I use `printf`
- `NR==1 { cell="th" ; }` will set `cell` to **th** for first line (`cell="th"` can be set in `BEGIN` clause, as `cell` is overwrite after each print)
- `th` stand for(?) Table Header and is meant to do what you intend (altough you can use it in any cell you like)

Comment: awesome bro  it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The data is separated by comma `,` but `awk` defaults to white space as a separator of fields in the input text.

Please try

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "<table>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}'  File.txt
```

The `-F` parameter gives the delimiter character for your data input (column separator in `File.txt`).

Comment: It work for me but how to add border styling as shown in above Output which is in yellow and code is printed on screen it should be write to html file in html file extension